# How to configure Angular2 Quickstart to run phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, angular, phantomjs, karma-runner

I am trying to figure out  how to run the tests of [Angular2 Quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) with phantomjs.

I thought these steps were enough to configure Karma:

**1. Clone the repository**

`$ git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git`
`$ cd quickstart`

**2. Install phantomjs and phantomjs launcher**

`$ npm install --save-dev phantomjs`
`$ npm install --save-dev karma-phantomjs-launcher`

**3. Change karma.conf.js**

// First change
require('karma-chrome-launcher') => require('karma-phantomjs-launcher')

// Second change
browsers: ['Chrome'] => browsers: ['PhantomJS']

**4. Install Quickstart App**

`$ npm install`

**5. Run tests**

`$ npm run test-once`

The following error is reported:

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
>     TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'System.config')
>     at karma-test-shim.js:30

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an error before that one: a 404 trying to find the `system-polyfills.js`.

> 404: /base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js

If you add that to the karma config, the error will go away.

```
files: [
  // System.js for module loading
  'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
  'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
```

Not quite sure what the difference is (why it's not needed for Chrome). I'm guessing [this issue](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/issues/274) is yours. You should ask them.

Comment: Yea, It's mine. I'm going to ask them. Thanks!